# Root parent for a parent child hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, parent-child, common-table-expression

I am referring book of Kimball's Data warehouse toolkit and want to implement a parent child hierarchy. I provide below code to create the table which contains parent child data:

```
   /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[COMPANY]    Script Date: 07/16/2020 15:05:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMPANY](
    [COMPANY_KEY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COMPANY_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PARENT_KEY] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (100, N'MICROSOFT', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (101, N'SOFTWARE', 100)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (102, N'CONSULTING', 101)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (103, N'PRODUCTS', 101)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (104, N'OFFICE', 103)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (105, N'VISIO', 104)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (106, N'VISIO EUROPE', 105)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (107, N'BACK OFFICE', 103)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (108, N'SQL SERVER', 107)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (109, N'OLAP SERVICES', 108)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (110, N'DTS', 108)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (111, N'REPOSITORY', 108)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (112, N'DEVELOPER TOOLS', 103)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (113, N'WINDOWS', 103)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (114, N'ENTERTAINMENT', 103)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (115, N'GAMES', 114)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (116, N'MULTIMEDIA', 114)
INSERT [dbo].[COMPANY] ([COMPANY_KEY], [COMPANY_NAME], [PARENT_KEY]) VALUES (117, N'EDUCATION', 101)
```

Then I use below query:

```
WITH REC (Root_ID,Level,Company_key,Parent_key,Company_Name)

As
(
Select 
t1.COMPANY_KEY,
1,
t1.COMPANY_KEY,
t1.PARENT_KEY,
t1.COMPANY_NAME
from company t1
where t1.PARENT_KEY ='103'

Union All

Select 
REC.Root_ID,
REC.Level+1,
REC_PLUS1.COMPANY_KEY,
REC_PLUS1.PARENT_KEY,
REC_PLUS1.COMPANY_NAME

from COMPANY as REC_PLUS1, REC
where REC.Company_key=REC_PLUS1.PARENT_KEY
)

Select S1.COMPANY_Key, S1.Parent_key,Level as Depth_from_Parent

from REC S1
left outer join COMPANY t1
on S1.PARENT_KEY=t1.Company_key
```

I get below output (Table-1):

[image]

I need following output (Table-2), in addition to current output shown above, i.e. highlighted portion by including root parent, in this case I filtered for Company_key=103:

[image]

In the anchor query, I have input the Company_Key='103' hard coded but I would like to use here this ID dynamically coming from another table, left joining. So for each Company_Key in that table, I should get the correct output filtered in the format as shown in table-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just tweak the CTE to fetch whatever list you want:

```
with cte as (
       select company_key, company_name, company_key as parent_key, 0 as lev
       from company
       where company_key in (103, 107)  -- whatever list you want here
       union all
       select c.company_key, c.company_name, cte.parent_key, 1 + cte.lev
       from cte join
            company c
            on cte.company_key = c.parent_key
      )
select * 
from cte
order by parent_key, lev;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcaf2dedefe09abea76b5c81a4f3ec74) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Brilliant. I think you answered my query. I will use in original case and revert if any further help needed. By the way, how to post this as an answer?